# Uso de Firebase database con html

Tags: javascript, html, base-de-datos, firebase, realtime-database

Hola buenas tardes espero que la persona que lea esto se encuentre bien :), estoy desarrollando un codigo de practica de un mini formulario web que permita escribir el nombre, apellido y correo del usuario.

Este es el codigo Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>

    <h1> Formulario de registro WEB </h1>

</head>



<body>
        <form >
            <!-- Nombre -->

            <label htmlFor="nameField"> Nombre </label>
            <input type="name" id="nameField"/>
        
            <!-- Apellido -->

            <label htmlFor="lastField"> Apellido </label>
            <input type="lastname" id="lastField"/>

            <!-- Correo -->
            <label htmlFor="emailField"> Correo </label>
            <input type="email" id="emailField"/>
        

        </form>

        <button class="btn btn primary" onclick="guardar()"> Enviar </button>
</body>

<!-- Librerias que vamos a usar -->

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>


<!-- Nuestros Scripts -->

<script type="module" src="../js/configuracion.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="../js/guardar.js"></script>
```

Y este es el de Javascript:

```
 function guardar(){
   db.collection("usuarios").add({
   nombre: document.getElementById("nameField").value,
   apellido: document.getElementById("lastField").value,
   correo: document.getElementById("emailField").value,
  })
    .then((docRef) => {
      alert("registro exitoso")
  })
   .catch((error) => {
      alert("Error en el registro")
  });
  }
```

Cabe recalcar que ya tengo otro archivo javascript con la config de firebase pero pues no voy a ensenarla jeje

Como iba diciendo, a la hora de correr el codigo la pagina carga el servidor todo bien, pero hay un error a la hora de darle a enviar que dice

**Uncaught ReferenceError: guardar is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (home.html:32:65)**

Pareciera que el html no detecta la funcion pero pues ya eh visto 30230 videos y guias, no encuentro una solucion por eso recorro aqui...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: guardar is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

indica que estás definiendo tu script como tipo "module":

```
<script type="module" src="../js/guardar.js"></script>
```

debes usar `type="text/javascript`" :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/guardar.js"></script>
```

los módulos deben ser importados, pero si usas `type="text/javascript"` indicas que el código se ejecutaría directamente desde `guardar.js`.

Comment: Gracias crack, logre resolverlo

Comment: Excelente @Clizco saludos